# R: delete duplicate rows that have been flipped

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

Row 1 and row 4 have the same information. The only difference is the column they appear under has been flipped.

I already know Yuma County and Cheyenne County are neighbors from row 1. I don't need this information reiterated in row 4.

```
           countyname fipscounty          neighborname fipsneighbor
1     Yuma County, CO       8125   Cheyenne County, KS        20023
2     Yuma County, CO       8125      Chase County, NE        31029
3 Cheyenne County, KS      20023 Kit Carson County, CO         8063
4 Cheyenne County, KS      20023       Yuma County, CO         8125
5 Cheyenne County, KS      20023      Dundy County, NE        31057
```

I don't mind that the counties appear more than once, I only care that the overall information in each row be different from the previous. I want to keep row 1 and delete row 4, so that the final looks like this

```
           countyname fipscounty          neighborname fipsneighbor
1     Yuma County, CO       8125   Cheyenne County, KS        20023
2     Yuma County, CO       8125      Chase County, NE        31029
3 Cheyenne County, KS      20023 Kit Carson County, CO         8063
5 Cheyenne County, KS      20023      Dundy County, NE        31057
```

How can I delete rows with duplicate information in the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another possible base R option:

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))),]
```

**Output**

```
         countyname fipscounty          neighborname fipsneighbor
1     Yuma County, CO       8125   Cheyenne County, KS        20023
2     Yuma County, CO       8125      Chase County, NE        31029
3 Cheyenne County, KS      20023 Kit Carson County, CO         8063
5 Cheyenne County, KS      20023      Dundy County, NE        31057
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(countyname = c("Yuma County, CO", "Yuma County, CO", 
"Cheyenne County, KS", "Cheyenne County, KS", "Cheyenne County, KS"
), fipscounty = c(8125L, 8125L, 20023L, 20023L, 20023L), neighborname = c("Cheyenne County, KS", 
"Chase County, NE", "Kit Carson County, CO", "Yuma County, CO", 
"Dundy County, NE"), fipsneighbor = c(20023L, 31029L, 8063L, 
8125L, 31057L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: one extra unique column on this and it will not work. Thats why i decided to only select the needed columns

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
idx <- duplicated(t(apply(CountyList[c('fipscounty', 'fipsneighbor')], 1, sort)))
CountyList[!idx, ]

          countyname fipscounty          neighborname fipsneighbor
1     Yuma County, CO       8125   Cheyenne County, KS        20023
2     Yuma County, CO       8125      Chase County, NE        31029
3 Cheyenne County, KS      20023 Kit Carson County, CO         8063
5 Cheyenne County, KS      20023      Dundy County, NE        31057
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `interaction` to generate unique factors after finding the name with "smaller" (i.e. first in alphabet) name as well as "larger" name. Then we can filter the `data.frame` based on that:

```
CountyList <- read.table(text="countyname fipscounty          neighborname fipsneighbor
1     'Yuma County, CO'       8125   'Cheyenne County, KS'        20023
2     'Yuma County, CO'       8125      'Chase County, NE'        31029
3 'Cheyenne County, KS'      20023 'Kit Carson County, CO'         8063
4 'Cheyenne County, KS'      20023       'Yuma County, CO'         8125
5 'Cheyenne County, KS'      20023      'Dundy County, NE'        31057")


fname <- pmin(CountyList$countyname,CountyList$neighborname) #Get first name
lname <- pmax(CountyList$countyname,CountyList$neighborname) #Get last names

duplicate.key <- as.numeric(interaction(fname,lname)) # Create factors from interaction and convert to numeric

CountyList[match(unique(duplicate.key),duplicate.key),] # Only keep first occurence


           countyname fipscounty          neighborname fipsneighbor
1     Yuma County, CO       8125   Cheyenne County, KS        20023
2     Yuma County, CO       8125      Chase County, NE        31029
3 Cheyenne County, KS      20023 Kit Carson County, CO         8063
5 Cheyenne County, KS      20023      Dundy County, NE        31057
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach.

First `unite` all columns together into `new_col` (i.e. to paste all columns together). Then split the `new_col` back to it's individual pieces and `sort` them. Save this into `new_col2`. Next we only keep the `distinct` rows of `new_col2`. Finally removes the newly created columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  unite("new_col", everything(), sep = "_", remove = F) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new_col2 = paste(sort(str_split(new_col, "_", simplify = T)), collapse = "")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct(new_col2, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("new_col"))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  countyname          fipscounty neighborname          fipsneighbor
  <chr>                    <int> <chr>                        <int>
1 Yuma County, CO           8125 Cheyenne County, KS          20023
2 Yuma County, CO           8125 Chase County, NE             31029
3 Cheyenne County, KS      20023 Kit Carson County, CO         8063
4 Cheyenne County, KS      20023 Dundy County, NE             31057
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(countyname = c("Yuma County, CO", "Yuma County, CO", 
"Cheyenne County, KS", "Cheyenne County, KS", "Cheyenne County, KS"
), fipscounty = c(8125L, 8125L, 20023L, 20023L, 20023L), neighborname = c("Cheyenne County, KS", 
"Chase County, NE", "Kit Carson County, CO", "Yuma County, CO", 
"Dundy County, NE"), fipsneighbor = c(20023L, 31029L, 8063L, 
8125L, 31057L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```